# "TypeError: status.map is not a function" - TypeScript using useState & Map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand why I'm having this Error on TS, when I write a letter on input an error popup **"TypeError: status.map is not a function"**, is my first time using TS.

this is my original code on github -> https://github1s.com/SantGT5/Front-JW/blob/dev/src/Component/Search.tsx

this is where the error is ->

```js
interface foundUser {
  name?: any;
  map?: any;
}

const [status, setStatus] = useState<foundUser>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchSearch() {
      try {
        const response: any = await api.post("/search", { name: status.name });

        setStatus({ ...response.data });
      } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err.response);
      }
    }
    fetchSearch();
  }, [status.name]);
  
  
        <ol>
        {status.map((elem: any) => {

          <li>{elem.name}</li>

        })}
      </ol>
```

And, is correct to say interface -> **map?: any** ?

Comment: Initially `status` is an array, and that's how you treat it when you `.map` over it, but the dependency for `useEffect` is `status.name` (undefined on an array) and you're treating the `response.data` as an object (which you're shallow copying for some reason). It's unclear what the actual shape of the data is, but your code doesn't deal with it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
setStatus({ ...response.data });
```

You are settings it as an object with `response.data` inside.
You can't map through an object, only arrays.

- Edit:
  You actually can loop through objects, but it's done differently.
  Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) out if relevant.

Comment: Changing `{ ...response.data }` to `[...response.data]` should fix it. Unless `response.data` is not an array, then more details are needed.